# How to broadcast a message in a network?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm working on a client-server application written in C. I want to broadcast a message to all the machines available on the local network.

How can I do that using the usual socket system calls in C?

Comment: "in the network" is too vague. Do you mean only the local network?

Comment: I meant in the local network. Thanks bortzmeyer, i found my answer: 192.168.0.255 :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just send the message to the broadcast address of your subnet, which for 192.168.0.0/24 is 192.168.0.255, or just broadcast to 255.255.255.255.

Answer (score 9):

you have to use UDP to send a broadcast message over a network. when creating your socket using the `socket()` function, specify `AF_INET` for the `family` parameter and `SOCK_DGRAM` for the `type` parameter. on some systems, you have to enable the sending of broadcast packet by setting the `SO_BROADCAST` socket option to 1, using `setsockopt()`.

then use the `sendto()` function call to send a datagram, and use `255.255.255.255` as the destination address.  (for datagram sockets, you don't need to call `connect()`, since there is no 'connection').

in standard implementations, this address broadcasts to all computer in the local network, this means that the packet will not cross gateway boundaries and will not be received by computers using a network mask diferent from the network mask of the sending computer.

Comment: What's the difference of using the `255.255.255.255` and a `224.0.0.0` IP addresses?

Comment: @AlexisWilke : the 224.0.0.0/4 range is reserved for multicast. multicast is a whole different beast than broadcast: services are grouped, a specific host needs to "join" a multicast group in order to receive the multicast packets sent to this group, some groups are well defined and are assigned specific ip address. note however that some groups behave as broadcast groups (224.0.0.1 for example). also note that support for multicast is not mandatory for ipv4. please see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) and [tldp](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Have a look at UDP sockets.**

I recomend [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#datagram). Have a look at 6.3 Datagram Sockets

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special address of 255.255.255.255 to send a broadcast message to every computer on the local network.

For more info see section [IP Network Broadcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address#IP_network_broadcasting).